# Probability of correctly guessing 12 zodiac signs without replacement

Tags: probability

I just watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfkwAAi4t2M&t=4s) where someone assigns a zodiac sign to twelve different individuals. There is one of each sign.

My question, Guessing at random, (this was not quite at random), what number of people are you expected to guess correctly? And with what probability are you expected to guess a given number of people correctly? 
i.e. What are the odds of getting 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. correct.

Comment: By linearity, you expect to guess exactly one right.  For the second part, well it's just a [binomial process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with success probability $\frac 1{12}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general expression for the probability that exactly $k $ of $n $ objects will be labelled correctly is
$$
p_{nk}=\frac {! (n-k)}{n!}\binom nk=\frac {! (n-k)}{k!(n-k)!}=
\frac1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!},
$$
where $!m$  is the number of [derangements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), aka subfactorial.

Here $\binom nk $ counts the number of ways to place $k$ correctly labelled objects, $! (n-k)$ counts the number of ways to wrongly label the rest objects, and $n! $ counts all possible ways to label the objects.

The expected number of correctly guessed people is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k p_{nk}=1.
$$

Comment: (0, 0.3678794413212816)
(1, 0.3678794392336059)
(2, 0.18393973214285714)
(3, 0.06131319811875367)
(4, 0.015328414351851852)
(5, 0.0030654761904761905)
(6, 0.0005111882716049383)
(7, 7.275132275132276e-05)
(8, 9.300595238095239e-06)
(9, 9.185773074661965e-07)
(10, 1.3778659611992944e-07)
(11, 0.0)
(12, 2.08767569878681e-09)

I think that's the probability for guessing each number correctly, if the process is truly random. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHalden Thank you for posting the numerical values!